# Apollo GraphQL Nested Mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

need some help on nested mutations.

Abstracted scenario is this:

I want to combine 2 mutation calls on apollo-server to first create a a `Customer` then create an `Address` for that customer. The `Address` mutation needs a `customerID` to be able to do this but also has information from the original overall mutation that it needs access to.

Here's the generic code:

```
makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: gql`
    type Mutation {
      createCustomerWithAddress(customer: CustomerRequest!, address: AddressRequest!): Response
    }
    input CustomerRequest {
       name: String!
    }

    input AddressRequest {
       address: String!
       city: String!
       state: String!
       country: String!
    }

    type Response {
       customerID: Int!
       addressID: Int!
    }
  `,
  resolvers: {
    Mutation: {
      createCustomerWithAddress: async (_, {customer}, context, info) => {
        return await api.someAsyncCall(customer);
      }
    },
    Response: {
      addressID: async(customerID) => {
        // how do we get AddressRequest here?
        return await api.someAsyncCall(customerID, address);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

There's a lot of complexity I'm not showing from the original code, but what I wanted to get at is just at the root of how to access request params via sub mutations, if even possible. I don't really want to pass down `address` from the top mutation to the sub mutation.

Comment: Follow up question?

Is there a better way to chain such mutations? From the front end UI, I want to be able to make one call to graphql apollo server that will make 2 API calls, one for creating a contact and another for creating an address. The address will need the contactID that is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `Response` field in resolvers. `createCustomerWithAddress` should return an object shaped like `Response`.

```
resolvers: {
    Mutation: {
      createCustomerWithAddress: async (_, {customer, address}, context, info) => {
        // create customer
        const customerId = await api.CreateCustomer(customer);
        // create address and assign customerId
        const addressId = await api.CreateAddress({ ...address, customerId });
        // return response
        return { customerId, addressId };
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: I've updated the example... maybe I'm chaining mutations incorrectly here but I need to wait for one update/mutation to occur to get an ID `customerID` and then add that to the address

Comment: @ChrisFricke you create both the customer and address within the same resolver. I updated the example.

Comment: @ChrisFricke was I able to answer your question?

Comment: hey @silent, yeah I'm able to do it that way it just seems not to use graphql correctly but maybe that is. What is different from this than writing this as just an express orchestration call aside from being able to select the fields?

This is a simplified example and I honestly have it separated out w/ two different schemas and mutations, one for address and one for customer and have been trying to just delegate that call out to each on this group mutation. Does that make sense? In the mutation resolver, I just delegateToSchema to each one of those, but it still doesn't feel right.

Comment: @ChrisFricke As far as I know, this is the right way. I think you're basically asking what advantages Graphql has over REST - https://www.howtographql.com/basics/1-graphql-is-the-better-rest/